# Maven is automatically skipping tests

Tags: maven, testing, testng, jboss-arquillian

How come that Maven is skipping all of my tests by default?I have a `pom.xml` with few profiles and I am not able to run my tests through neither of them. One of my profiles looks like

```
<profile>
        <id>jsf-test</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <version>${jboss.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jsf.tests</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-app</artifactId>
                <version>${jsf-app.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>                
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-jsf-app</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.jsf.tests</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jsf-app</artifactId>
                                        <version>${jsf-app.version}</version>
                                        <type>war</type>
                                        <destFileName>jsfapp.war</destFileName>
                                        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests> <!-- desperate trial -->
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>${testng.listeners}</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

If I run `mvn verify -Pjsf-test` then the project is compiled, `jsf-app` artifact is correctly copied into target directory and tests are skipped. `mvn verify -Dtest=TestCalculator` has the same result. I am using `Arquillian` and `TestNG` to perform the actual tests but I am not sure if it matters for this question.

**EDIT**

Running in debug will give (the relevant part)

```
[DEBUG]   (s) reportFormat = brief
[DEBUG]   (s) reportsDirectory = /home/pmensik/Work/workspace/epp-test/cdi-arquillian-    test/target/surefire-reports
[DEBUG]   (f) reuseForks = true
[DEBUG]   (s) runOrder = filesystem
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = true
[DEBUG]   (s) skipTests = false
[DEBUG]   (s) systemPropertyVariables = {jsfPortlet=true}
[DEBUG]   (s) testClassesDirectory = /home/pmensik/Work/workspace/epp-test/cdi-arquillian-test/target/test-classes
[DEBUG]   (s) testFailureIgnore = false
[DEBUG]   (s) testNGArtifactName = org.testng:testng
[DEBUG]   (s) testSourceDirectory = /home/pmensik/Work/workspace/epp-test    /cdi-arquillian-test/src/test/java
[DEBUG]   (s) trimStackTrace = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useFile = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useManifestOnlyJar = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useSystemClassLoader = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useUnlimitedThreads = false
[DEBUG]   (s) workingDirectory = /home/pmensik/Work/workspace/epp-test/cdi-arquillian-test
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: org.jboss.gatein.test:cdi-portlet-test:6.1-ER01 @ /home/pmensik/Work/workspace/epp-test/cdi-arquillian-test/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@3c3483ec
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

My simplest test looks like this

```
public class Test {

    @Drone
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive.class, new File("target/CDIPortlet.war"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase{
        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running with `-DskipTests` somehow? What does `mvn clean verify` or `mvn clean install` do?

Comment: Try running with `-X` to get debug output, then look at the surefire plugin's configuration.  I would also suspect a plugin inheritance problem.  Is the surefire plugin configured in a parent POM?

Comment: and where are your tests defined?

Comment: @vikingsteve - exactly the same result

Comment: @user944849 - see my edit. And yes, I am inheriting from really simple POM, there is just a definition of Surefire plugin in `pluginManagement` with skipped configuration, nothing else

Comment: @PetrMensik Ok, does the default configuration for `maven-surefire-plugin` have include or exclude patterns? Look through all the parent poms. If so, adding `<excludes> <exclude>none</exclude> </excludes>` in your profile `<configuration>` might help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The debug output shows this:

```
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = true
```

which not only skips *running* the tests, it will also skip *compiling* them.  Check the parent POM (directly referenced by this POM, also any corporate POMs or super POMs introduced by Arquillian) to see where this flag is being set, if you're curious.

The fix is to add

```
<skip>false</skip>
```

to the surefire plugin config in this module, or add

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=false
```

to your command line.

[Reference](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip)

Comment: <skipTests>true</skipTests> -- tests are compiled, but not runned.

Comment: <skip>true</skip> -- tests are not even compiled.

Comment: This works for me, but I have no idea why it works. Since none of my pom.xml files are setting this to false.

Comment: I think adding `-Dmaven.test.skip=false` to command while there's `<skip>true</skip>` in the POM is ignored. Just a note. It didn't work for me anyway until I changed it to `<skip>false</skip>`

Comment: @Nom1fan - correct. If the value has been hardcoded like that, the value in the property can no longer be used. If you have access to the POM, removing the hardcoding and using the properties is the way to go.